# How to keep track of daily data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, data-collection

In my rails application, I want to keep several daily metrics in order to see how this data changes over times. In other words, if I want to see how many times a user logged in on a particular date (and therefore allowing me to accumulate this data over times).

Some of this data I can figure out through queries, such as the number of posts a user made on a particular day (because the post model includes a date). However, there are many different daily metrics I want to keep track of.

I thought of creating a DataPlayers model which has data for every player and every day creating a new instance of this, but I don't think that is the best approach.

Are there best practices for this type of data collection?

Comment: If I understand what you'er saying, I think your approach is best. Running a "job" at night that tallies the results for the day and records them is likely best-- then just query those results to get the changes over time.

Comment: And you think a new model is the best approach for storing that data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gem like [SqlMetrics](https://github.com/KaktusLab/sql_metrics) to track events as they happen.

It stores the events in your own database so its easy to query them via sql.